# What does the phrase "that is" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Here is a sentence from a space adventure game's description:

> Let’s come together, build a spaceship and get started. After this cup of
>   tea and scones, **that is**.

I  am confused about the meaning of the last sentence. Maybe it is due to the ambiguity of the phrase "that is" here. I know its [lexical meaning](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/that-is), but it doesn't seem to fit here.

Comment: Why do you think "to be specific" or 'to be precise" doesn't fit?

Comment: On a second thought, it makes sense in the sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just being witty. *Obviously* we'll relax and have a cup of tea before embarking on a great adventure. So the antithesis is intentional.